# How can I find the actual link which is related to the javascript

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

I'm a student stuyding the bioinformatics.

I'm trying to make a crawler where I can put the lists of queries and get the results automatically.

The site I'm interested in is the GEO DataSet site.

www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gds/

If I wish to send a query like 'lung cancer', I can use the following address.

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gds/?term=lung+cancer.

And there are 549 pages showing up.

I can get the results of the first page, but I don't know how to move to the next page.

I mean, how can I move to the next page by changing the URL?

The Next button is linked as "www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gds/?term=lung+cancer#" and I don't think it's the actual URL that button is linked to.

I'm new to the JavaScript, but I heard the hash sign (#) is processed in the JavaScript

I wonder if there is something I can do like 
"http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gds/?term=lung+cancer&page=2"
so that I can move to the second page.

Comment: Is crawling your only option? They seem to provide programmatic access: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/info/geo_paccess.html

Comment: @AtesGoral Thanks a lot!! I didn't know they provided such a tool. But I still wonder if it is impossible to find the actual link or it is just hard to find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use any debugger tool (Firebug for Firefox, WebDeveloper for Chrome) you should be able to monitor the network traffic. If you do that, you'll see, that by clicking the next button a form is submitted, sending data via post method. However, when concatenating the post data to a get string you can also get to the next page. The following url lets you access to second page of the result set (warning: really, really long!):

```
http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gds/?term=lung+cancer?term=lung+cancer&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Gds.Entrez_PageController.PreviousPageName=results&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Gds.Gds_ResultsPanel.Gds_DisplayBar.sPresentation=docsum&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Gds.Gds_ResultsPanel.Gds_DisplayBar.sPageSize=20&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Gds.Gds_ResultsPanel.Gds_DisplayBar.sSort=none&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Gds.Gds_ResultsPanel.Gds_DisplayBar.FFormat=docsum&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Gds.Gds_ResultsPanel.Gds_DisplayBar.FSort=&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Gds.Gds_ResultsPanel.Gds_DisplayBar.FileFormat=docsum&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Gds.Gds_ResultsPanel.Gds_DisplayBar.LastPresentation=docsum&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Gds.Gds_ResultsPanel.Gds_DisplayBar.Presentation=docsum&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Gds.Gds_ResultsPanel.Gds_DisplayBar.PageSize=20&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Gds.Gds_ResultsPanel.Gds_DisplayBar.LastPageSize=20&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Gds.Gds_ResultsPanel.Gds_DisplayBar.Sort=&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Gds.Gds_ResultsPanel.Gds_DisplayBar.LastSort=&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Gds.Gds_ResultsPanel.Gds_DisplayBar.FileSort=&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Gds.Gds_ResultsPanel.Gds_DisplayBar.Format=&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Gds.Gds_ResultsPanel.Gds_DisplayBar.LastFormat=&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Gds.Gds_ResultsPanel.Entrez_Pager.cPage=1&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Gds.Gds_ResultsPanel.Entrez_Pager.CurrPage=2&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Gds.Gds_ResultsPanel.Gds_ResultsController.ResultCount=10973&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Gds.Gds_ResultsPanel.Gds_ResultsController.RunLastQuery=&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Gds.Gds_ResultsPanel.Entrez_Pager.cPage=1&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Gds.Gds_ResultsPanel.Gds_DisplayBar.sPresentation2=docsum&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Gds.Gds_ResultsPanel.Gds_DisplayBar.sPageSize2=20&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Gds.Gds_ResultsPanel.Gds_DisplayBar.sSort2=none&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Gds.Gds_ResultsPanel.Gds_DisplayBar.FFormat2=docsum&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Gds.Gds_ResultsPanel.Gds_DisplayBar.FSort2=&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Gds.Gds_ResultsPanel.Entrez_Filters.CurrFilter=all&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Gds.Gds_ResultsPanel.Entrez_Filters.LastFilter=all&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Gds.Gds_ResultsPanel.Gds_MultiItemSupl.Taxport.TxView=list&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Gds.Gds_ResultsPanel.Gds_MultiItemSupl.Taxport.TxListSize=5&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Gds.Gds_ResultsPanel.Gds_MultiItemSupl.RelatedDataLinks.rdDatabase=rddbto&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Gds.Gds_ResultsPanel.Gds_MultiItemSupl.RelatedDataLinks.DbName=gds&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Gds.Gds_ResultsPanel.Discovery_SearchDetails.SearchDetailsTerm=%22lung+neoplasms%22%5BMeSH+Terms%5D+OR+lung+cancer%5BAll+Fields%5D&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Gds.Gds_ResultsPanel.HistoryDisplay.Cmd=PageChanged&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.DbConnector.Db=gds&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.DbConnector.LastDb=gds&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.DbConnector.Term=lung+cancer&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.DbConnector.LastTabCmd=&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.DbConnector.LastQueryKey=1&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.DbConnector.IdsFromResult=&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.DbConnector.LastIdsFromResult=&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.DbConnector.LinkName=&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.DbConnector.LinkReadableName=&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.DbConnector.LinkSrcDb=&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.DbConnector.Cmd=PageChanged&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.DbConnector.TabCmd=&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.DbConnector.QueryKey=&p%24a=EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Gds.Gds_ResultsPanel.Entrez_Pager.Page&p%24l=EntrezSystem2&p%24st=gds
```

This complete GET string contains all search parameters like items per page, search terms, display and way more. You should be able to figure out which parameter is used for the offset (cPage and CurrPage are your friends) and then alter it to your needs.

EDIT: Btw, to find javascript events bound to an HTML element, you can use the bookmarklet found at http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event+2

Comment: Thank you so much Paul!! I really appreciate it. I spent so much time struggling with it and you saved my life. Have a nice day!

Comment: If that solved your question, please consider accepting my answer.